# rat 3D Brain Atlases

Tags: software

I'm looking for publish an image of the rat brain for an article with a specific places selected on 3D. Just like this picture:

[image]

I heard about the Elsevier program BrainNavigator 3.2, but the webpage is down. Anyone know a dataset, program, webpage or any source where to find information about this?.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Biology SE - no cognitive aspect.

Comment: @AliceD You do realize that psychologists and cognitive neuroscientists still have a need to know neuroanatomy.  I think you're knee-jerking a bit on some of these.

Comment: (it's not a good question to begin with, but has been closed for the wrong reason)

Comment: @ChuckSherrington - I'm not sure I understand what knee-jerking is, but it sounds erm.. nasty. You are right. The reason for closing was actually not Bio related, as it would admittedly and undoubtedly be close-voted at Bio as well due to the fact the question is solely on computer software. I should have brought that up as primary reason. My apologies. Let me know what you mean with knee-jerking, as you are referring to other questions as well. Please see my promised revival on meta: http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/966/neurobiology-rivalries-part-v-a-newer-hope

Comment: @AliceD I will check it out!  I just meant that some of the closings were more of a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patellar_reflex to certain things than to the overall nature of the post.

Comment: (I realize it came out harsher than it was meant to.  Some of the posts/closings I've commented on already)